How to set Full Screen with Angular (ionic/Capacitor.js)
I am trying to set fullscreen with angular(ionic/capacitor.js)
divEle This is my div element
Below is my code.
/*
* This function is used for video full screen
*/
fullScreen() {
   try{
     if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
       console.log("document fullscreen")
       if (this.divEle.nativeElement) {
          console.log("div element called")
          // event.stopPropagation();
          if (this.divEle.nativeElement.requestFullscreen) {
            console.log("requestFullscreen")
            this.divEle.nativeElement.requestFullscreen();
          } else if (this.divEle.nativeElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            console.log("mozRequestFullScreen")
            this.divEle.nativeElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (this.divEle.nativeElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            //In Safari it's comes here
            console.log("webkitRequestFullscreen")
            this.divEle.nativeElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          } else if (this.divEle.nativeElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
            console.log("msRequestFullscreen")
            this.divEle.nativeElement.msRequestFullscreen();
          } else {
            //For IOS Mobile It's comes here
            console.log("else part called")
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        }
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log("full screen Error :",e)
    }

  }

In Android, it works fine. In IOS Safari, it's working. But when I checked with the IOS Mobile Device, It went on to another part.
Can anyone suggest any specific requirement for IOS Mobile, or is there any other field required for an IOS device?angu
